# 2 dimensional complex number multiplication

Tags: complex-numbers, complex-multiplication

so we know that $$i^2 = -1$$
and from Hamilton who said that $$i^2=j^2=k^2=-1$$
we get
$$ ij = -ji = k$$
$$ki = -ik = j$$
$$jk = -kj = i$$

but what if I am in the complex plane of i and j and the z axis is the set of reals. What does ij equal? My guess, from the intuition that multiplication by i results in a 90 degree rotation, is that $$ij = ji$$ But that is so unsatisfying. It looks like a simple commutation. Somehow I feel like I want to get a single symbol out of that operation for it to mean something.

EDIT: I am sorry for the confusing presentation. Let me start anew. Consider the number system consisting of real numbers, i, and j. Define a 3D cartesian(?) coordinate system where the 'z' axis is the set of reals and the 'x' axis is the set of i numbers and the 'y' axis is the set of j numbers. Every point in this space can be represented as

$$A + B i + C j$$

What is the result of

$$(3 + 2 i) * 4 j$$

I get

$$12 j + 8 ij$$

So what does the quantity $ij$ reduce to so I can graph it?

Is it $$-j$$
I am looking for the results of the following multiplications table:
$$ij=?$$
$$ji=?$$

Comment: I'm not an expert on this so I might be wrong and I might get hammered, but I think the complex plane would be the plane formed by the axis of reals and the $i$ axis.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're asking. The quaternions are not the same as the complex numbers. Restricting the quaternions to additive subgroups along the $i$-$j$, $j$-$k$, &c. planes does not change the multiplication table. In general a product of two elements in the $i$-$j$ plane, for instance, is no longer in the $i$-$j$ plane.

Comment: Also if you know that $ij = -ji$ and think that $ij = ji$, then you must have that $-ji =ij = 0$. So you’re right that things aren’t adding up (although 0 is a single symbol :))